# Pulling last six digits from JMETER JSONPath value

Tags: regex, jmeter, jsonpath

I am working with Jmeter, and I have a JSON extractor that will successfully pull a value from a JSON object returned from a HTTP call. I only need the last 6 digits of this value, that happen to come after a colon.
E.G. 12345678:111222

I can't figure out how to just get those last 6 digits to store in a variable to use at a later time. I'm not sure if I can do this through a JSONPath regex type expression, or after the JSON value is stored, using another JMETER post processor to pull those digits and store them in another variable.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this using the BeanShellPreProcessor. You can use this tool to write Java code to interact with variables and such.

vars.get("variablename") grabs the variable currently being used in Jmeter.
vars.put("variablename",VALUE) will write the new variable information back.
Everything in between is just regular java. I just used the substring method to cutout most of the string, wrote it back, and then used it.

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Beanshell is known to have performance issues. It's recommended to use JSR223 processors instead.